# How to disable Lazy loading in EF Core 3.1.3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have tried to disable Lazy loading those two ways:

**1)**

```
public SqlDbContext(DbContextOptions<SqlDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
     this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

**2)**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<SqlDbContext>(options => {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlDbContext"));
        options.UseLazyLoadingProxies(false);
});
```

And I don't use the key word "virtual" in the navigation.

Unfortunately the lazy loading is stil working. I want to disable it, to force me using only eager loading, so throw an error when I forget to use Include().

But with thouse two approaches the query is still returning the results.

Comment: Unexpected entieis in your graph can be caused by entities were loaded by a previous query on the same DbContext, because the Change Tracker will fixe-up the Navigation Properties.

Comment: Well.. Should what you have written, be valid even during debug when the query is getting the data for first time?

Comment: I have just tried to modify the query the way to get data I was not loading before, and Still getting the data...

Comment: Then you'll need to post a short, self-contained repro in your question.